# how to read the every position of search keyword from the array of files

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code now I can only find the last position of the word.

```
    string[] textFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/PCRequestFiles");
    foreach (string fileName in textFiles)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

        for (int x = 0; x < lines.Length; x++)
        {
            int warnPos = lines[x].IndexOf(((TextBox)sm1.FindControl("Findtxt")).Text,
                          StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

            if (warnPos > 0)
            {

                 ((Label)sm1.FindControl("Findlbl")).Text = "The data is in the File " + fileName.Substring(29) + " at line " + ( x + 1) + " ";               
                        dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["FileName"] = fileName.Substring(29);
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        gvFileGenStatus.DataSource = dt;
                        gvFileGenStatus.DataBind();

            }

        }
    }
```

Thanks for all the help in advance ).

Comment: Hope that you are able to explain what is the error/difficulty you are facing with  this code

Comment: I need to change this code to display all the position of the keyword  now it only showing the last position

Comment: `if (warnPos > 0)` has to be `if (warnPos > -1)` since this method returns 0 as valid index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes;

`if (warnPos > 0)` has to be `if (warnPos > -1)` since this method returns 0 as valid index.
`Findtxt` label only displays the last index found. So we need to concatenate all the lines found.

```
string[] textFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/PCRequestFiles");

foreach (string fileName in textFiles)
{
     string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

     for (int x = 0; x < lines.Length; x++)
     {
         int warnPos = lines[x].IndexOf(((TextBox)sm1.FindControl("Findtxt")).Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

         //Change to > -1
         if (warnPos > -1)
         {
             //Add += to concatenate string
             ((Label)sm1.FindControl("Findlbl")).Text += "The data is in the File " + fileName.Substring(29) + " at line " + (x + 1) + " ";
             dr = dt.NewRow();
             dr["FileName"] = fileName.Substring(29);
             dt.Rows.Add(dr);
             gvFileGenStatus.DataSource = dt;
             gvFileGenStatus.DataBind();    
         }    
     }
}
```